# Create dummies based on a window of observations (in R or Stata)

Tags: r, stata

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), month = c(201701, 201702, 
201703, 201704, 201705, 201706, 201707, 201708, 201809, 201810, 
201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201705, 201706, 201707, 
201708, 201709, 201710, 201711, 201712, 201801, 201809), desired_output = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

For each id, I would like to create a dummy that equals 1 if a given month is in a window of 7 observations (three before and three after).

For example, if a given month is the second observation for a given id, I want the dummy to equal 0 because there are not three observations for this id before it.

I may have potentially more than a single "1" for each id if there is more than one month fitting into a window of 7 observations.

The expected output is in a column named "desired_output".

My real window consists of 25 months (12 after and 12 before), but I use 7 so that the example dataset is not too big.

Stata example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str2 A str6 B str14 C
"id" "month " "desired_output"
"1"  "201701" "0"             
"1"  "201702" "0"             
"1"  "201703" "0"             
"1"  "201704" "1"             
"1"  "201705" "1"             
"1"  "201706" "0"             
"1"  "201707" "0"             
"1"  "201708" "0"             
"2"  "201809" "0"             
"2"  "201810" "0"             
"2"  "201811" "0"             
"2"  "201812" "1"             
"2"  "201901" "0"             
"2"  "201902" "0"             
"2"  "201903" "0"             
"3"  "201705" "0"             
"3"  "201706" "0"             
"3"  "201707" "0"             
"3"  "201708" "1"             
"3"  "201709" "1"             
"3"  "201710" "1"             
"3"  "201711" "1"             
"3"  "201712" "0"             
"3"  "201801" "0"             
"3"  "201809" "0"             
end
```

Comment: Why is `month` 201711 == 0? Shouldn't that be 1?

Comment: That is true. Sorry. I will correct my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just observations a window within each group means "get X first and last rows".

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0, otherwise use "group_by"

rnge <- 1:3

df %>% 
  mutate(out = if_else(row_number() %in% 
                 c(!!rnge, n() - (!!rnge - 1)), 0, 1), .by = id) %>% 
  print(n = Inf)
# A tibble: 25 × 4
      id  month desired_output   out
   <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 201701              0     0
 2     1 201702              0     0
 3     1 201703              0     0
 4     1 201704              1     1
 5     1 201705              1     1
 6     1 201706              0     0
 7     1 201707              0     0
 8     1 201708              0     0
 9     2 201809              0     0
10     2 201810              0     0
11     2 201811              0     0
12     2 201812              1     1
13     2 201901              0     0
14     2 201902              0     0
15     2 201903              0     0
16     3 201705              0     0
17     3 201706              0     0
18     3 201707              0     0
19     3 201708              1     1
20     3 201709              1     1
21     3 201710              1     1
22     3 201711              1     1
23     3 201712              0     0
24     3 201801              0     0
25     3 201809              0     0
```

`dplyr` < **1.1.0**

```
rnge <- 1:3

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(out = if_else(row_number() %in% c(!!rnge, n() - (!!rnge - 1)), 0, 1)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you! If instead of 3 after and 3 before, I want 12 after and 12 before I need only to change to "1:12", right?

Comment: Yeah, thats right. Also change 0:2 to 0:11.

Comment: You can pull those out as variables if you have to change those values frequently. I add an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution using `tidyverse` if I understand your logic:

```r
library(tidyverse)

window <- df %>% 
  split(.$id) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    ~.x %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(
        tmp_index = dplyr::row_number(),
        max_index = max(tmp_index) - 3,
        mindex = min(tmp_index) + 3,
        desired_output2 = ifelse(tmp_index >= mindex & tmp_index <= max_index, 1, 0)
      ) %>% 
      select(id, month, desired_output, desired_output2)
  ) 

print(window, n = 25)
#> # A tibble: 25 × 4
#>       id  month desired_output desired_output2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1     1 201701              0               0
#>  2     1 201702              0               0
#>  3     1 201703              0               0
#>  4     1 201704              1               1
#>  5     1 201705              1               1
#>  6     1 201706              0               0
#>  7     1 201707              0               0
#>  8     1 201708              0               0
#>  9     2 201809              0               0
#> 10     2 201810              0               0
#> 11     2 201811              0               0
#> 12     2 201812              1               1
#> 13     2 201901              0               0
#> 14     2 201902              0               0
#> 15     2 201903              0               0
#> 16     3 201705              0               0
#> 17     3 201706              0               0
#> 18     3 201707              0               0
#> 19     3 201708              1               1
#> 20     3 201709              1               1
#> 21     3 201710              1               1
#> 22     3 201711              1               1
#> 23     3 201712              0               0
#> 24     3 201801              0               0
#> 25     3 201809              0               0

identical(window$desired_output, window$desired_output2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But the latest version of purrr that I have is 0.3.4 and it does not contain function "list_rbind". I am now allowed to download any new packages.
Do you know of another way?

Comment: You can change `map` to `map_dfr` and remove `list_rbind()` - edited the response to show that.

Answer (score 1):

In Stata your dataset first needs major surgery as you have metadata in your data and too many string variables. It's as if you have just misread the data in from a spreadsheet and done nothing to set up the date properly.

The first solution differs from others because the code takes the gap before the last observation literally. It seems you really want just to count observations before and observations after, so the second solution echoes that desired output.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str2 A str6 B str14 C
"id" "month " "desired_output"
"1"  "201701" "0"             
"1"  "201702" "0"             
"1"  "201703" "0"             
"1"  "201704" "1"             
"1"  "201705" "1"             
"1"  "201706" "0"             
"1"  "201707" "0"             
"1"  "201708" "0"             
"2"  "201809" "0"             
"2"  "201810" "0"             
"2"  "201811" "0"             
"2"  "201812" "1"             
"2"  "201901" "0"             
"2"  "201902" "0"             
"2"  "201903" "0"             
"3"  "201705" "0"             
"3"  "201706" "0"             
"3"  "201707" "0"             
"3"  "201708" "1"             
"3"  "201709" "1"             
"3"  "201710" "1"             
"3"  "201711" "1"             
"3"  "201712" "0"             
"3"  "201801" "0"             
"3"  "201809" "0"             
end

// start of surgery 
foreach v in A B C {
    rename `v' `=`v'[1]'
}

drop in 1 
destring, replace 
gen mdate = ym(floor(month/100), mod(month, 100))
format mdate %tm 
// end of surgery 

// ssc install rangestat needed 
rangestat (count) wanted=id, int(mdate -3 3) by(id)
replace wanted = wanted == 7 
bysort id (mdate) : gen t = _n 
rangestat (count) wanted2=id, int(t -3 3) by(id)
replace wanted2 = wanted2 == 7 

list, sepby(id)

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     | id    month   desire~t     mdate   wanted    t   wanted2 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   201701          0    2017m1        0    1         0 |
  2. |  1   201702          0    2017m2        0    2         0 |
  3. |  1   201703          0    2017m3        0    3         0 |
  4. |  1   201704          1    2017m4        1    4         1 |
  5. |  1   201705          1    2017m5        1    5         1 |
  6. |  1   201706          0    2017m6        0    6         0 |
  7. |  1   201707          0    2017m7        0    7         0 |
  8. |  1   201708          0    2017m8        0    8         0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  9. |  2   201809          0    2018m9        0    1         0 |
 10. |  2   201810          0   2018m10        0    2         0 |
 11. |  2   201811          0   2018m11        0    3         0 |
 12. |  2   201812          1   2018m12        1    4         1 |
 13. |  2   201901          0    2019m1        0    5         0 |
 14. |  2   201902          0    2019m2        0    6         0 |
 15. |  2   201903          0    2019m3        0    7         0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
 16. |  3   201705          0    2017m5        0    1         0 |
 17. |  3   201706          0    2017m6        0    2         0 |
 18. |  3   201707          0    2017m7        0    3         0 |
 19. |  3   201708          1    2017m8        1    4         1 |
 20. |  3   201709          1    2017m9        1    5         1 |
 21. |  3   201710          1   2017m10        1    6         1 |
 22. |  3   201711          1   2017m11        0    7         1 |
 23. |  3   201712          0   2017m12        0    8         0 |
 24. |  3   201801          0    2018m1        0    9         0 |
 25. |  3   201809          0    2018m9        0   10         0 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

This extends to other window lengths, so -12 to 12 and 25 fit your real problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will set up the data properly next time. Sorry about that and thank you for providing a solution even with this issue.